# 404 on POST but 200 on GET

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I met a problem that when I make a POST request, the server responses with 404 error, while making GET request, it responses with 200.

Here are the methods that I have tried:

```
 $.ajax({
     type:"POST", 
     url: "script.php",
     data:{
         imgBase64: data
     }
 }).done(function(o) {
     console.log('saved');
 });
```

And:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , dataURL);
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open( 'post', 'script.php', true );
xhr.send(data);
```

Further more I have tried to include:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK", true);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in the php script. But none of them works.
Anyone has idea? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the php script. By the way, I am using nodejs...

```
<?php
// requires php5
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Comment: your full php script?

Comment: What are you using to serve the php with?

Comment: @JasonPrawn I am posting the php script with a base64 encoded image , and calling the script to download the picture. It seems that the script was not called at all.

Comment: @Robert What I was wanting to know is more about how you're serving the PHP. You can't post directly to a script you need to be serving it using something like php-fpm with nginx or PHP CLI's built in server: `php -S localhost:8000`.

Comment: @JasonPrawn Sorry I am not sure what you mean... I am using nodejs as the server an nothing else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to nodejs and finally I found that I should write a function in server.js to process the get request.